# TypeError: Cannot read property 'quote' of undefined React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch, undefined

Just to summarise, I'm creating a quote-generator using React js. The data is getting fetched from a mock API using React axios.

However, when I'm trying to display the quote it gives me that above error

line where I get error: {quotes[quoteIndex].quote}

(quotes) gets populated with the data
(quoteIndex) is basically an index in an array
(.quote) is the attribute from the data

Please find the relevant code

```
// sample from .json file data
"quotes": [
    {
    "id":0,
    "quote": "Genius is one percent inspiration and ninety-nine percent perspiration.",
    "author": "Thomas Edison"
  },
  {
    "id":1,
    "quote": "You can observe a lot just by watching.",
    "author": "Yogi Berra"
  }
 ]
}


const [quotes, setQuotes] = useState([]);
const [quoteIndex, setQuoteIndex] = useState(0);

// fetching the data
const getData = async() =>{
        try{
            const response = await Axios.get("/quotes");

            if(response && response.data){
                setQuotes(response.data);
                console.log(response.data);
            }

        }catch(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
        
    }


//this inside the return statement
<div className="styleQuote">
                    <h3 className="styleText" >{quotes[quoteIndex].quote}</h3>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common problem when dealing with data that is loaded asynchronously.

Here's how I would suggest debugging this to understand your problem:

1. Remove the offending code so that you can observe what's happening.
2. Add `console.log(quotes)` in your component. You will see that it logs `[]` and then again with your array.
3. Next add `console.log(quotes[quoteIndex])`. Notice that it logs `undefined` and then an object.

Consider that while the value is `undefined`, you cannot treat it like an object and attempt to access properties on it.

4. Add a check to make sure the value is an object before using it:

```js
// Nullsafe operator
quotes[quoteIndex]?.quote
// Or ternary
quotes[quoteIndex] ? quotes[quoteIndex].quote : null
```

Here is a simulated example:

```js
const async_quotes = [
  {
    "id":0,
    "quote": "Genius is one percent inspiration and ninety-nine percent perspiration.",
    "author": "Thomas Edison"
  },
  {
    "id":1,
    "quote": "You can observe a lot just by watching.",
    "author": "Yogi Berra"
  }
 ]

const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const index = 1;

const Example = () => {
  const [quotes, setQuotes] = useState([]);
  
   useEffect(() => {
     setTimeout(() => {
       setQuotes(async_quotes);
     }, 3000);
   }, []);
   
   console.log("quotes:", quotes);
   console.log("single quote:", quotes[index]);
   
   return <div>{quotes[index] ? quotes[index].quote : ''}</div>
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: quotes[quoteIndex] ? quotes[quoteIndex].quote : null
this check worked for me, but just to confirm what condition is this checking (quotes[quoteIndex]), I understand if that's true this (quotes[quoteIndex].quote) will get displayed else null

Comment: It's doing a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) check. In this scenario it's just verifying that it is not `undefined` (which is falsy)

Comment: Sorry I'm asking this again.
<h3 >{ quotes[quoteIndex].quote}</h3> //this gives me that above error.
However, using the ternary check, runs fine
<h3 >{quotes[quoteIndex] ? quotes[quoteIndex].quote : null}</h3>

Does this mean it wasn't undefined earlier as well ?